# Any ideas for a logo?

Tags: discussion

Any ideas for a logo?

Perhaps something like <kbd>:vi</kbd>, <kbd>:help vi</kbd>, or <kbd>:ask-vi</kbd> (not like this, but properly drawn as a key).

Comment: Do we even get a logo until we leave beta?

Comment: From the 7 essential meta questions: "Each community should work out how they’re going to come up with a logo on their own"

Comment: Instead of `:ask vi`, maybe `:he vi` or `:help vi`?

Comment: @muru Yeah, `:help vi` is better

Comment: @Jasper Yeah, that link mentioned this question, which is why I posted it, [but I just found that this is out of date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta) ... :-/

Comment: @muru - I vote for `:help vi`

Comment: I vote for `alias emacs=vim` please. `:)`

Comment: If I could upvote comments, I would vote for @muru > `:help vi`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't get a custom logo until graduation, which is still a long way away. (Furthermore, Stack Exchange's designers are very, very often (if not always) the ones who choose the logo and other design elements, not the community.)

Comment: If we agree on a nice logo and find someone at stackexchange to support it we might get lucky. At [Aviation.SE](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/178/new-icon-for-aviation) we did get our logo a month into the public beta.

Comment: Why not the VIM icon with the letters `SE` overlaid. It's well known (VIM logo) it's recognizable even at small resolutions like a favicon, Oh and it's green 'cause green is awesome!

Comment: Also the upvote and downvote buttons should be keyboard keys with the letters k and j on them (respectively).

Comment: I don't really see any reason *not* to discuss this, as long as we're all aware of what "beta" means.

Comment: @Sukima ^A and ^X surely?